# MySQL - employ created_date and updated_date?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

In MySQL, is there an easy way for the following:

- On creation, both `created_date` and `updated_date` are set to the same `TIMESTAMP`
- On subsequent edits, `updated_date` is changed to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Why is only one field allowed to use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as its default value?  Why can't I have one default to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and the other use it only `on update`?

If I use `now()` for `created_date` and `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `updated_date`, will they be the same on the creation of a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way it is :)

But seriously, it's usually easier (less surprises) when you set those dates explicitly with 'now()' when you create/update the row.

Comment: If I use `now()` for `created_date` and `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `updated_date`, will they be the same on the creation of a row?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I would say so.

Comment: I believe `ON UPDATE` only triggers when an `UPDATE` command is ran for a row. Setting `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is what gives it the current timestamp on `INSERT`